# SC.connect() with soundcloud does not work with phonegap

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, authentication, soundcloud

I'm creating a webapp using phonegap.
I'm trying to connect a user to my app using the `SC.connect()`. My code works perfect in the browser. I get the user object and all the attributes. But when I run the app on android with phonegap it does not work. I get the pop up as it should, enter the username and password, press the connect button, but then the pop up that says

> This pop up should automaticly close in a few seconds

But it never closes. What am I missing here?

This is my code:

```
function onBtnClick() {
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    redirect_uri: scr='MY_REDIRECT_URI',
});

SC.connect(function() {
    SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
        $.jStorage.set('userInfo',me); // store the user to storage
        console.log("Logged in userId: "+ me.id); 
        console.log('Logged in username: '+me.username);
        });     
    });         
}
```

Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: Anyone? I really need this to work.